# Catching overflow during exponentation of int or long long int

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior, integer-overflow

Is there any way to catch overflow when using pow() function with int or long long int.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  int a = 2;//or long long int a = 2
  int b = 50;//or long long int b = 50
  if(!exponentation_overflows(a,b))//some function to check if there is no overflow
  {
    cout<<pow(a,b)<<endl;
  }

}
```

Comment: How would you imagine an overflow of the floatingpoint value to look like? Already when the precision fails? Or not before the absolute maximum of the float representation kicks in?

Comment: I can think about catching that using assembly inline but I rather wait to see if there is an standard way of doing that.

Comment: Which error handling do you need that ain't specified at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow ?

Comment: AFAIK, the standard doesn't define a pow function that returns an integer type - so you can check the return value with std::isnan(answer). This may be implementation-dependent, though. In your case, pow(a, b) will promote a to double and return double.

Answer (score 0):

I know this isnt what you're asking but you could write your own pow function that checks if the result is less that the previous one.

Answer (score 0):

> [...] with int or long long int.

*Since C++11*, the standard function [`std::pow`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow) has a specific overload for *integer* numbers.

In that case, your arguments will be converted in their `double`'s representation.

---

> Is there any way to catch overflow [...]

Yes, the standard function already provides a mechanism for error handling.

In case of overflow:

> If a pole error or a range error due to overflow occurs, ±HUGE_VAL, ±HUGE_VALF, or ±HUGE_VALL is returned.

So your code should be something like:

```
#include <cmath>

void pow_wrapper(const int base, const int exp) {
  const double result = std::pow(base, exp);
  if (result == HUGE_VAL) {
    // overflow detected
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As pow returns a double, which has a much larger range than either int or long long int, you could have:

```
bool exponentiation_overflows(int a, int b) {
    return pow(a, b) > double(MAXINT); // or double(MAXLONGLONG)
}
```